# how to manage termstore group

Tags: term-store, managed-metadata

We have configured a metadata service application in our sharepoint 2010 farm and associated with the default proxy group. The default proxy group is associated with a webapplication. The metadata has two termset group and both are available for the associated webapplication however we want to control the termset group based on the given permission, means if userX logs in to the webapplication he should be able to see both however only one termset group should be visible for the userY and nothing should be there for other  users.

Is it possible? If so, how to achieve this in sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Planning managed metadata](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530389.aspx) on Technet.

These articles also describe the [roles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424398.aspx) and how to set up group managers and [term store admin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424400.aspx)